# How do I recover my email account

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I need help recovering my old accounts and I have a bunch to find and I've tried looking up by phone number and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you give any more details?

In general, there is usually more than one way to access email from an email provider. If you have lost your password, you can use a password reset function from the website version of your email.

It's purposely meant to be a little difficult, so it's harder for people like abusive users to get access to accounts.